# SMS through WSO2 esb proxy services

Tags: wso2, esb

can we send SMS through WSO2 esb. i don't want number to be hard coded in proxy services.
if any one done this please provide details

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WSO2 ESB's [Twilio Connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Twilio+Connector) for your requirement. It has [SMS sending](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Twilio+Connector#TwilioConnector-WorkingwithSMSmessages) capabilities and you can use that for your requirement.

If you don't need the number to be hard coded (assuming you send the number with the request) you can read the number from the incoming message and then set the number to a [property](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Property+Mediator) . You can use that property to get the number inside the Twilio Connector

Comment: but we had our SMS gateway same we need to use for sending sms.

Comment: In that case http://mytecheye.blogspot.com/2013/01/wso2-esb-sending-sms-alerts-for-failures.html might help you.

Comment: I had done this with the help of above blogs. but can we put transportsender configuration in ESB proxy. instead of axis 2 xml.